# Assigning multiple values in a case statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to do the following inside a cursor. 
Is is possible to use just one case staement to assign multiple values ?

```
CASE 
    when @region = ‘Region 1’ then @sum_region1 = @sum_region1 + @sum_actual
    when @region = ‘Region 2’ then @sum_region2 = @sum_region2 + @sum_actual    
    when @region = ‘Region 3’ then @sum_region3 = @sum_region3 + @sum_actual
    when @region = ‘Region 4’ then @sum_region4 = @sum_region4 + @sum_actual 
End
```

Comment: Is your question if that code is working or about changing it?

Comment: I want this as part of a select statement and this code is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    IF @region = 'Region 1'
    BEGIN
       SET @sum_region1 = @sum_region1 + @sum_actual
    END
    IF @region = 'Region 2'
    BEGIN
       SET @sum_region2 = @sum_region2 + @sum_actual
    END
    IF @region = 'Region 3'
    BEGIN
       SET @sum_region3 = @sum_region3 + @sum_actual
    END
    IF @region = 'Region 4'
    BEGIN
       SET @sum_region4 = @sum_region4 + @sum_actual
    END
```